# Reading token balances

Tags: web3js, erc-20

I am trying to read the token balance of a certain address as well as reading the amount of ETH that has been sent to a smart contract from that address.

Currently I have:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'));

abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs": 
[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]');
TokenContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

contractInstance = TokenContract.at('[TOKEN CONTRACT ADDRESS]');
var balance = contractInstance.balanceOf(userAddress);
```

The abi is a standard ERC20 abi, but balanceOf returns an object (r {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array(1)}), shouldn't it return an integer? How should I get the token balance from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result value is a [bignumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/). You can just use toString to get value.

```
balance.toString()
```